# Change HTML page for shapefile published on GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I have uploaded a shapefile to GeoServer. Here is how it looks when I open it in OpenLayers through Layer Preview.

[OpenLayer page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQq1x.jpg)

I want to do the following.

1. I want to disable the extra options available e.g. WMS version, CQL filters, etc.
2. I want to disable the zoom in/ zoom out buttons.
3. I want to retrieve attribute values from shapefile into drop down boxes
   so that user can select attributes and fire custom query.
4. I want to fire custom CQL/ECQL query from the user selected attributes.

Where is the html page for this OpenLayers link located? I couldn't find it in data_dir/www/ in geoserver folder.

For the time being how can I fire CQL query? I tried entering columnname = 'Value for Column' and clicked apply filter. But that did not work.

For later how can I

1. Retrieve data from shapefile
2. Fire query on click of a button for filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML is dynamically generated by geoserver so you won't find them, but you can save the generated page to your computer and edit the saved files as you need.

Comment: I am new to GIS in general. How do I link my custom html page to geoserver? I am using Ubuntu.

I could not find any beginner friendly tutorial to follow.

Answer (score 4):

GeoServer provides the `Layer Preview` page as a convenient way of checking that a layer is loaded and displaying correctly. This is **not** designed as a production page.

You should investigate the [OpenLayers library](http://openlayers.org) to produce a custom WMS viewer for your project's needs.

Comment: I'll look into creating custom openlayers wms viewer. How do I go about retrieving data from geoserver and sending query to geoserver?

Comment: you use a WMS request to fetch data and a WFS-T request to change the data on GeoServer. Look around this site for examples.

Comment: What about cql/ecql?  Can i use those instead of wfs-t?  I don't need to change anything on the server map but need to apply filters.

Comment: Then just a WMS query